# how to calculate percentage

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I need to calculate percentage in c# and bind it in `xaml`
in a list of item i need to `%`the active count by complete count
and bind it in a list called employee list if any one know please help me to figure it out

[my calculation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxMie.png)

```
<TextBlock  
    x:Name="complainceValue"  
    Grid.Column="6"   
    Text="{Binding competencylevel}" 
    FontSize="17"
    FontWeight="SemiBold"
```

```
  public String competencylevel { get; set; }
```

Comment: Provide a minimum code not post as a image

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) but provide it as (properly formatted) text

Answer (score 1):

To calculate a percentage in C# and bind it to an employee list in XAML, you can follow these steps:

First, define a class for an employee object that includes properties for the active count and complete count. For example:

```
public class Employee
{
    public int ActiveCount { get; set; }
    public int CompleteCount { get; set; }
}
```

Next, create a method that calculates the percentage based on the active and complete counts. This method should return a float value representing the percentage:

```
public float CalculatePercentage(Employee employee)
{
    return (float)employee.ActiveCount / employee.CompleteCount * 100;
}
```

Create a list of employee objects and populate it with data.

```
List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>
{
    new Employee { ActiveCount = 10, CompleteCount = 20 },
    new Employee { ActiveCount = 5, CompleteCount = 10 },
    new Employee { ActiveCount = 3, CompleteCount = 6 }
};
```

In your XAML file, define a ListView or other control to display the employee list. Bind the ItemsSource property to the list of employees and define a DataTemplate to specify how each employee should be displayed.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Employees}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

This is the basic structure for calculating and displaying percentages for a list of employees in C# and XAML. To complete the implementation, you can add a TextBlock or other control to the DataTemplate to display the percentage value for each employee.